# Cannot change Javadoc Location for Google Maps Api in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

I am trying in eclipse Indigo to change the JavaDoc location for Google APIs [4.0.3] maps.jar from [android-sdk-path]/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-15/docs/reference/ to [android-sdk-path]/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-15/docs/maps_apis/, where it is actually located. Klicking "Validating..." finds the JavaDoc.

But when I save an close the dialog, my changes are lost and next time, when I check the JavaDoc location, the original location is shown again.

Does anybody know how the location of the JavaDoc can be changed? Seems to be configured by the Google APIs [4.0.3] library container, but I have no idea how this can be changed.

I see the same behaviour in my Windows 7 and my Linux machine. And this also happens only, when I want to change the Javadoc Location of the maps.jar or effects.jar. Therefore I don't think, it is a Problem with my installation (eclispse platform 3.7.0, android devtools 16.0.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem on multiple machines.  I have no problems changing the JavaDoc path for other JARs, but if I try to change any of the "Google APIs" JAR files, the setting is not persisted.  I'm able to set it, validate it, press Ok, go back in and it is reset back to the old setting.

I ended up just creating a folder link that mapped the new "maps_apis" folder to "reference" and now it works. On a Windows computer, you can go to the "add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-15\docs" folder in a console window and and run...

mklink reference maps_apis

I suppose you could also just copy all the files from the maps_apis folder to a reference folder.  Until a better solution comes along, this is good enough for now.

Comment: This worked well for me (the other solutions did not) - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried in the way suggested by @amit sharma
you can download eclipse indigo again. there might be some issue with your version of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as i am working on Helios but it seems that for Indigo also it will work.

> Open the Java Build Path page of a project via Right click on a project → Properties → Java Build Path. On the "Libraries" tab expand the library's node, select the "Javadoc location" attribute and press Edit.Enter the location to the file which contains the Javadoc. Click "OK".

Comment: I did exactly that, but when I save the changes and reopen the dialog, all changes are lost

Comment: @Dominik Is there a 'references' folder in 'maps_apis' directory ?

Comment: @sam no there isn't one, this is the root folder of the documentation (i.e. has package-list and index.html files in it)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Eclipse Indigo but i FIXED it. Use the following steps to solve this problem.

> Open Eclipse | Project | Properties | Java Build Path | Select
>   'Libraries' Tab
>
> Expand 'Android X.X' | then expand android.jar | Select '@ Javadoc
>   location' | click Edit
>
> Choose 'Javadoc URL' option, click Browse and select the path to
>   Javadoc
>
> Click Validate.

Note: The selected javadoc location path must have 'package-list' and 'index.html' file in it. 
Otherwise you will get following error while validating

> 'Location might be invalid. Files 'package-list' and 'index.html' that
>   are typically available at the root of documentation created by the
>   Javadoc tool have not been found.'

Therefore, add the correct path and eclipse will validate the path.

---

If the above solution does not solve the problem, Try this

> Close Eclipse
>
> Locate your Eclipse Workspace.
>
> Delete '.metadata' folder from eclipse Workspace path. (Backup before
>   deleting)

**Note: Deleting '.metadata' will erase your eclipse settings and preferences and Android ADT plugin will be removed. So you need to reinstall ADT plugin and reconfigure eclipse preferences.**

But it should work.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, inculding hitting the "validate" Button, which gave a positive result. My problem is, that the changes get lost after I close the dialog.

Comment: @Dominik is your path validating successfully ?

Comment: I'm not sure, that this is a problem with my eclipse installation, since I see the same behaviour in my Windows 7 and my Linux installation.

Comment: @Dominik Javadoc location is configured by eclipse and not by 'Google APIs [4.0.3] library container', Try to move the original location directory to somewhere else on disk and see what happens.

Comment: the original directory, as it is configured before I try to change it, does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, you have to create the default path that has eclipse.
In my case I had to rename the folder where it was index.html.